# How to control animation speed and direction in BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine

I would like to be able to control an object moving along a path in the BGE. I have looked at the Action actuator, but that seems to just play the animation. I want to be able to control the speed and direction of the object as it moves along the path. Something like a car going down a road.
Is there some way to accomplish this??

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any info and this, so since i figured it out, i would post the answer. I used logic block and a python scrip. The example is not for a follow path, but just a simple cube animation.

The game goes as follows:
Press space key to start animation, press again to stop the action.
Press the F key to speed up the animation, and press the S get to go slower.

I included some images.

```
import bge
```

def main():

```
# max frame of animation
maxFrame = 100

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

frameAct = cont.actuators['Frame']

currentFrame = own.get(frameAct.propName)

# limit speed to between 1 and 10
speed = own['speed']
speed = max(1,speed)
speed = min(10,speed)

speedInc = (0.10*speed)

currentFrame = currentFrame + speedInc

if currentFrame > maxFrame:
    currentFrame = 1

frameAct.value = str(currentFrame)
cont.activate(frameAct)
```

main()

[image: Overall layout][image: Logic Blocks]

Comment: Note: When using this on a follow path constraint, the action must be baked into key frames for this to work.